# Pandas Dataframe: count number of IDs based on occurence of words in a text column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this :

```
id   comment

1    its not proper
2    improvement needed
3    organization is proper
4    registration not done
5    timelines not proper
```

For these set of words ['proper','organization','done'] I want to calculate the number of ids they are occuring in. So the output should be like :

```
proper         3
organization   1
done           1
```

I have tried this using a for loop :

```
word_list = ['proper','organization','done']
final _list = {'proper':0,'organization':0,'done':0}
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    for word in word_list:
        if word in row['comment'].split(' '):
            final_list[word] += 1
```

is there any way to do this without using any for loop...

Comment: You don't want `for loop` at all?

Comment: @WoodChopper, out of curiosity I timed [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33410555/5276797) (without a for loop) and compared it to the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33407499/5276797). As is often enough the case, the for loop happens to be faster (12 ms vs. 22 ms). Lesson: don't always blindly try to avoid `for` loops!

Comment: get_dummies will be very slow since additional columns. And time will increase exponentially with no of search words lets say there are some 1000 different words we needs to search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str.contains` and sum over bool values in list comprehension of `words`

```
In [23]: words = ['proper','organization','done']

In [24]: pd.DataFrame([[wrd, df['comment'].str.contains(wrd).sum()] for wrd in words])
Out[24]:
              0  1
0        proper  3
1  organization  1
2          done  1
```

Comment: I don't think .contains() is same as what OP is doing in his code, .contains() would match partial words as well.

Comment: Well I guess OP is not much concern about exact word match. He was splitting for counting..

Comment: I am looking for exact match, I was splitting by space and matching.

Comment: Then use regex operation `exactmatch = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(word_list))` then `df.comment.map(lambda x: re.findall(exactmatch,x))` returns lists of words join the list to count.

Comment: @WoodChopper How would performance be affected compared to the original solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str` accessor and then `.str.split()` function, to split the strings in `comment` . Using `df['comment'].str.split().values` would get you the array of arrays containing words. Example -

```
In [35]: df['comment'].str.split().values
Out[35]:
array([['its', 'not', 'proper'], ['improvement', 'needed'],
       ['organization', 'is', 'proper'], ['registration', 'not', 'done'],
       ['timelines', 'not', 'proper']], dtype=object)
```

Then, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the strings you want. Example -

```
word_set = {'proper','organization','done'}
result = Counter(x for lst in df['comment'].str.split().values
                   for x in lst if x in word_set)
```

This does not remove the `for` loop, but uses *generator expression* , which can be bit faster than conventional `for` loop.

Also using `word_set` would make it faster , since search in `set` is constant time, whereas searching in list is O(n).

---

Demo -

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   id                 comment
0   1          its not proper
1   2      improvement needed
2   3  organization is proper
3   4   registration not done
4   5    timelines not proper

In [35]: df['comment'].str.split().values
Out[35]:
array([['its', 'not', 'proper'], ['improvement', 'needed'],
       ['organization', 'is', 'proper'], ['registration', 'not', 'done'],
       ['timelines', 'not', 'proper']], dtype=object)

In [36]: word_set = {'proper','organization','done'}

In [37]: result = Counter(x for lst in df['comment'].str.split().values
   ....:                    for x in lst if x in word_set)

In [38]: result
Out[38]: Counter({'proper': 3, 'done': 1, 'organization': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: `get_dummies` also does the trick without any `for` loop:

```
df['comment'].str.get_dummies(' ').sum()[['proper','organization','done']]

Out[151]: 
proper          3
organization    1
done            1
```

Note: filtering after the sum handles missing words neatly.

---

**Original answer**: Apparently all the answers so far use a `for` loop. One way of avoiding it would be to use `pd.value_counts`:

```
df['comment'].str.split().apply(pd.value_counts)[['proper','organization','done']]

Out[149]: 
   proper  organization  done
0       1           NaN   NaN
1     NaN           NaN   NaN
2       1             1   NaN
3     NaN           NaN     1
4       1           NaN   NaN
```

All you have to do is sum the resulting dataframe:

```
_.sum()

Out[150]: 
proper          3
organization    1
done            1
```

You'd only need to adjust the code if one of the words in the list is not anywhere in the text.

---

Answer (score 1):

```
In [105]:
words = ['proper','organization','done']
for word in words:
    df[word] = df.comment.str.contains('\\b' + word + '\\b' , case = True , regex = True)

Out[105]:
comment                         proper  organization    done
its not proper                   True   False          False
improvement needed               False  False          False
organization is proper           True   True           False
registration not done            False  False          True
timelines not proper             True   False          False

In [103]:    
df.iloc[: , 1:].sum()
Out[103]:
proper          3
organization    1
done            1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.str.contains()` method in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['id', 'comment']
data = [[1, 'its not proper'],
        [2, 'improvement needed'],
        [3, 'organization is proper'],
        [4, 'registration not done'],
        [5, 'timelines not proper']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
word_list = ['proper','organization','done']
row_counts = {word: df[df.comment.str.contains(word)].shape[0]
              for word in word_list}
print row_counts
# output is:
# {'proper': 3, 'organization': 1, 'done': 1}
```

Comment: I don't think .contains() is same as what OP is doing in his code, .contains() would match partial words as well.